# Изменение Boot.ini на Windows7

Tags: windows, windows-7, dual-boot

Делается удаленная отладка WinDbg. Имеются две виртуальные машины. Отладчик установлен на машине (host), которая связана через порт с трассируемой ОС (target). Виртуальные машины, соединяются через pipe c host-системой. Вот пример файла Boot.ini для Windows xp.

```
[boot loader]
timeout=30
default=multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(1)\WINDOWS
[operating systems]
multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(1)\WINDOWS="Microsoft Windows XP Professional"
/noexecute=optin /fastdetect /sos
multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(1)\WINDOWS="Microsoft Windows XP Professional"
/fastdetect /sos /debug /debugport=com1 /baudrate=115200
```

В Win7 файла Boot.ini нет. Но есть замечательная утилита BCDEDIT. Подскажите, как с ее помощью настроить загрузчик аналогично тому как это делалось для XP

Comment: Рекомендую настраивать при помощи https://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/ - он даже линуксы цмеет прописывать. Впрочем, говорят, он работает только при классическом биосе, а с UEFI не дружит, но не могу это проверить.

Comment: спасибо, посмотрю на него, но все же хотел бы разобраться со способом который описал, кажется что не достает только "правки" Boot.ini что не выглядит сложным

Comment: Переводить и писать в ответ - слишком много. Так что оставлю это здесь: [Remote Debugging Using WinDbg](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/setting-up-a-network-debugging-connection)

Comment: О, ещё вот это, ближе к ответу на вопрос: [Setting Up Kernel-Mode Debugging over a Serial Cable Manually](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/setting-up-a-null-modem-cable-connection)

Comment: То, что нужно, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Источник: [Setting Up Kernel-Mode Debugging over a Serial Cable Manually](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/setting-up-a-null-modem-cable-connection)

> **Важно!** Перед использованием `bcdedit` для изменения загрузочной информации вы должны временно остановить такие опции безопасности как `BitLocker` и `Secure Boot` на тестовом PC. Вы сможете включить их заново, когда отладка завершена, и вы отключили `kernel debugging`.

1. На отлаживаемом компьютере откройте `Command Prompt` с повышенными привилегиями и введите следующие команды, где `n` это номер COM порта, используемого для отладки этого компьютера, и `rate` - скорость соединения, используемая для отладки:

---

```
bcdedit /debug on
bcdedit /dbgsettings serial debugport:n baudrate:rate
```

---

**Для сведения:** Скорость соединения должна совпадать на головном и отлаживаемом компьютерах. Рекомендуемая скорость: 115200.

2. Перезагрузите отлаживаемый компьютер.

Аналогичные инструкции для отладки виртуальной машины через виртуальный COM порт есть здесь: [Setting Up Kernel-Mode Debugging of a Virtual Machine Manually using a Virtual COM Port](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/attaching-to-a-virtual-machine--kernel-mode-)